# reference to static function in PHP

Tags: php, syntax, static-functions

is possible get reference to static function and run? like this:

```
namespace vendor\foo;

class Bar
{
    public static function f1()
    {
        echo 'f1';
    }
    public static function f2($id)
    {
        echo 'f2: '.$id;
    }

}
```

and

```
$fs = array(
    'f1'=>\vendor\foo\Bar::f1,
    'f2'=>\vendor\foo\Bar::f2
);

$fs['f1']();
$fs['f2']('some id');
```

or the only way is `call_user_func` ?

**note:** php 5.3

Comment: You've already written the code needed to test this. When you run it does it work?

Comment: no does not work. and say: `Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'f1'`

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: some thing like anonymous function. but static function.(static function has some advantage. for example auto complete, class auto loading and ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options to do this

1. using a string variable for the class name and the method name
2. using callbacks together with call_user_func()
3. using Reflection

The following examples shall demonstrate these options:

```
<?php

namespace vendor\foo;

class Bar {

    public static function foo($arg) {
        return 'foo ' . $arg;
    }   
}
```

Option 1 : Using a string variable for the classname and the method name:

```
/* prepare class name and method name as string */
$class = '\vendor\foo\Bar';
$method = 'foo';
// call the method
echo $class::$method('test'), PHP_EOL;
// output : foo test
```

Option 2 : Perpare a callback variable and pass it to `call_user_func()` :

```
/* use a callback to call the method */
$method = array (
    '\vendor\foo\Bar', // using a classname (string) will tell call_user_func()
                       // to call the method statically
    'foo'
);

// call the method with call_user_func()
echo call_user_func($method, 'test'), PHP_EOL;
// output : foo test
```

Option 3 : Use ReflectionMethod::invoke() :

```
/* using reflection to call the method */
$method = new \ReflectionMethod('\vendor\foo\Bar', 'foo');

// Note `NULL` as the first param to `ReflectionMethod::invoke` for a static call.
echo $method->invoke(NULL, 'test'), PHP_EOL;
// output : foo test
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember if this is supported in PHP 5.3, but you can do this in 5.4:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor;

class Foo
{
  public static function bar()
  {
    echo "bar\n";
  }
}

$funcs = [
  'bar' => ['\Vendor\Foo', 'bar']
];

$funcs['bar']();
```

Comment: It basically is the same in PHP 5.3, but the `[..]` short array syntax isn't available in PHP 5.3.

Comment: @kokx no `$fs['f1']();` not supported. and php say: `Call to undefined function \vendor\foo\Bar::f1() in ...` but `\vendor\foo\Bar::f1();` or `call_user_func($fs['f1']);` work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.3 it depends on the type of callback being used. The example you gave, where it is a *method* of an object, cannot be invoked in the manner described. If the example had been a procedural *function* you could invoke it using the code you gave.

I'm not sure why this is the case from a technical understanding but my guess is that the PHP parser looks for a function named `\vendor\foo\Bar::f1` and it can't find one. If you wish to invoke a variable function, i.e. `$var()`, then `$var` **must** be a function and not an object method. If you wish to call a variable *method* then check out the examples below.

---

The following examples are valid ways to invoke variable *static object methods*:

```
<?php

class Foo {

    public static function a() {
        echo 'Foo::a()';
    }

    public static function b() {
        echo 'Foo::b()';
    }

}


$foo = 'Foo';
$aFunc = 'a';
$bFunc = 'b';

$foo::$aFunc();
Foo::$bFunc();
call_user_func('Foo::' . $aFunc);
call_user_func(array($foo, 'b'));

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is possible. But the way you are trying won't work. You have to use a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

```
$fs = array(
    'f1'=>array('\vendor\foo\Bar', 'f1'),
    'f2'=>array('\vendor\foo\Bar', 'f2')
);

$fs['f1']();
$fs['f2']('some id');
```

Comment: when use `$fs['f1']();` php say: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function \vendor\foo\Bar::f1()`. `{$fs['f1']}();` has syntax error.

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake. Callables are defined a little differently. Will edit the answer accordingly.